# Getting url of image on django/wagtail site

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

I have a wagtail site - where blogpages are rendered by looping through a streamfield (in which each block can have an image, a heading and some text):

```
<div class="col-md-8 mx-auto px-auto">
    <div class="conundrum mb-3">{{ page.category }}</div>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="meta">{{ page.date }}</p>
    <div class="intro my-4 py-4">{{ page.intro }}</div>

    {% for block in page.content %}
        <div class="pb-4">
        {% image block.value.image fill-1000x500 class='blog_image' %}
        <h2 class="py-2 my-2">
            {% include_block block.value.heading %}
        </h2>
        {% include_block block.value.text %}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I want the 'tweet this' button on the blogpage to include the first image on that page.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@PsymatikDotCom" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{page.title}}" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{page.intro}}"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://how_do_i_get_this_path" />
```

But it is not clear to me how to dynamically grab the url of the first image to enter it in the twitter:image section?

Answer (score 4):

See the Wagtail docs page on [How to use images in templates](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/images.html#full_url).

```
<head>
  {% image page.photo width-400 as tmp_photo %}
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ tmp_photo.full_url }}">
</head>
```

You can combine this approach with the [`first` Django template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#first).

```
<head>
{% with page.content|first as first_block %}
  {% image first_block.value.image width-400 as tmp_photo %}
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ tmp_photo.full_url }}">
{% endwidth %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each Image object Wagtail creates several [Rendition](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html) objects, in accordance all your [registred](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#image-formats-in-the-rich-text-editor) formats, so you need to refer to the Rendition object for a link to a specific image

Your case:

*templatetags.images.py*

```
from django import template
from wagtail.images import get_image_model
from wagtail.images.models import Rendition

Image = get_image_model()
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name="get_img_src")
def get_img_src(img: Image, spec: str) -> str:
    if not img:
        return ''

    rendition = img.get_rendition(spec)
    return rendition.attrs_dict['src']
```

*template.html*

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ block.value.image|get_img_src:"your_spec" }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Was also having this issue.
But i think i found the answer.
It's simple

```
{{ page.image.file.url }}
```